# Trivariate optimization problem with a set of inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given vectors $\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{n}_1, \mathbf{n}_2,\dots, \mathbf{n}_m \in \mathbb{R}^3$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^3}{\text{minimize}} & f(\mathbf{p}) = \left[\mathbf{q}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{p}\right]^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf{p}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{p} = 1\\ & \mathbf{n}_i^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{p} \ne 0, \quad \forall 1 \le i \le m\end{array}$$

Do you know any optimization method using which this problem can be solved?

Comment: The feasible region is not closed. You could just take any $p$ perpendicular to $q$ and then slightly perturb it so $n_i^T p \neq 0$.

Comment: Where are the inequality constraints?